# Do certificates contain private keys or other sensitive data?

Tags: certificates

Generally speaking, are certificates always non-sensitive? In the form of x509 certs, it's really just a public key and some metadata right?

I see some things that call "certificates" the combination of the x509 public key certificate and the private key. But that's not really a certificate at that point (PKCS#12) right? That's more of a "bundle"?

Am I missing something, or is the word "certificate" maybe misused at times? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This depends on what is considered *sensitive*. And this depends on the context.  For example it might already be considered sensitive information which domains are listed as subject alternative names in the certificate. Some of these domains might be already known by whoever views the certificate while others might be interesting new information, like maybe internal names.

Comment: Thanks for the response! I should have been more specific on what I meant by "sensitivity". I guess the metadata/fields of a certificate itself could be considered sensitive, but I was also making sure that my understanding that a private key (or any form of data that could diminish or eliminate encryption) is nowhere in a certificate, ever.

Comment: @ThomasStringer: Correct, the private key is nowhere in the certificate and it can also not derived from it. That's the main point of [public key cryptography](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Public-key_cryptography).